# how can I solve this problem after shuffling a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of objects and I would like to show them in a random order every time I open the app. this is the code:

```
final placesInCity = availablePlaces.where((city) {
  return city.cityId.contains(categoryId);
}).toList().shuffle();
```

//here I added the shuffle

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(categoryTitle!),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: placesInCity.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return PlaceItem(
        id: placesInCity[index].id,
        title: placesInCity[index].title,
        imageUrl: placesInCity[index].imageUrl,
        food: placesInCity[index].food,
        compass: placesInCity[index].compass,
        transportation: placesInCity[index].transportation,
      );
},
```

after I added the shuffle() all of the index turned red

Comment: what do you mean by `all of the index turned red`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shuffle` works `in-place` - it doesn't return a new shuffled list, but rather shuffles the existing one and returns `void`.
The problem here is that you are assigning the result of `shuffle` to a variable.

```
final placesInCity = availablePlaces.where((city) {
  return city.cityId.contains(categoryId);
}).toList();
placessInCity.shuffle();
```

Comment: Alternatively use the cascade operator: `final placesInCity = availablePlaces.where((city) => city.cityId.contains(categoryId)).toList()..shuffle();`.